# Jersey 2 client with basic Auth using POST method

Tags: java, jersey, client

I'm using jersey 1.X to call a REST API which required basic Auth, and my code works fine.
Lately I'm trying to upgrade jersey to a 2.x version and cannot figure out a way to call the REST API with post method.
Below is the jersey 1.X code which I currently use, Hope you guys can help me upgrading this code to jersey 2.x (Java 7)

Thanks in advance!

```
public static String requestAPIToken(String url) throws Exception{
    
    ClientResponse clientResponse   = null;
    WebResource webResource     = null;
    
    Client client = Client.create();
    client.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    client.setReadTimeout(5000);
    client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("username","password"));

    webResource = client.resource(url); 
    clientResponse  = webResource.post(ClientResponse.class);
    
    if (clientResponse.getStatus() == 200) {

        return clientResponse.getHeaders().getFirst("Authorization");

    } else {
        System.out.println( "Request API Token status Error: "+clientResponse.getStatus());
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Jersey 2.x also has a Basic Auth client feature. [See the docs](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e5463)

Comment: it has but couldn't find a way to call that using POST method